# How to keep thee value of a variable until I reset it?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 puzzle games, sub-games lets say, in my game. For each user earns some points. After game1 ends I set earned points to a public static int pointsGame1 variable. And so on for other games. I my main menu I have a box that should display total points. I do something like this:

```
boxTotalPoints.setText("" + pointsGame1 + pointsGame2 + pointsGame3 + pointsGame4);
```

Problem is when I start that activity I get 0000, cause start value for all variables is 0.

And the second problem I have is when I finish my game1 I add those points to my totalPoints variable, also public static int, like this:

```
Menu.totalPoints =+ pointsGame1;
```

But when I play second game it should total all my points and display it in mu total box, but instead I only get points from last played game. Also if I earned 60 points in my first game it will display 00060.

How to resolve those two things?

Comment: define all pointsGame1 , pointsGame2 , pointsGame3 , pointsGame4 as static variable and also make sure you reset them it to default value on your reset event(may b on button click event).

Comment: They are static variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SharedPreferences` in your Activity.

To be precise: using shared preferences from different activity/services/intents/... you should use it with mode MODE_MULTI_PROCESS (constant value int = 4). If not, file gets locked and only one process can write it at once!

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myapp",4);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
int points= pointsGame1 + pointsGame2 + pointsGame3 + pointsGame4;
editor.putInteger("points", points);
editor.commit();
```

---

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myapp",4);
points= preferences.getInteger("points", 0);
points= point+pointsGame1;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInteger("points", points);
editor.commit();
```

And any time you need to persist the points across Activities use the code above.

---

Then when you need to retrieve the points from any of your Activities/Processes:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myapp", 4);
points= preferences.getInteger("points", 0);
```

Comment: Do I use this in onCreate method? And can you edit your post to use my variables, just to see some stuff goes. Thanks.

Comment: @marjanbaz anywhere you need it, in any method in any of your Activities in your App. In onCreate() is OK as well (but I imagine that the structure of your code should be more complex, not having onCreate() only)

Comment: @marjanbaz if any of these answers helped you you could give back reputation, by accepting an answer (click green tick on the left) and/or upvoting an answer (click orange up arrow on the left). Good luck with your work! maurizio

Comment: I edited my comment, maybe you didn't see. Can you edit your post to use my variable names, just to see where they go?

Comment: @marjanbaz there you go! :-)

Comment: I tried to use your code but I don't get it how to. :( First two snippets are the same only in second one you have only one variable pointsGame1. Why's that? Also, in what activity do I use first snippet? And I had to change putInteger to putInt.